# Signature mismatch warning for overriding constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to override a constructor from a parent class. However PhpStorm is giving me a warning because the constructor override is incompatible as the signatures do not match.

Why does it give me a warning in the first place? Does JavaScript not allow overriding of constructors with different signatures?

It seems to run fine without any errors displayed in the console.

[image]

```js
class DDDSelector {
    /**
     * @typedef {NodeList} DDDSelector_elements - array of elements this selector is selecting
     */

    /**
     * @param {string|null} [tag] - html element tag name
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor(tag = null) {
        if (tag) {
            this.DDDSelector_elements = [document.createElement(tag)];
        }
    }
}

class PageDots extends DDDSelector {
    /**
     * @typedef {DDDSelector} holder - the wrapper element for the dots.
     * @typedef {Array.<DDDSelector>} dots - an array of dots
     * @typedef {DDDSelector} selectedDot
     */

    /**
     * Creates all dots for one slideshow.
     * @param {number} count - the number of dots to create
     * @param {Flickity} slideshow - the slideshow
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor(count, slideshow) {
        super('div');
    }

}
```

**Edit 1:** I'm assuming the rules for overriding constructors in JavaScript is the same as it is in PHP and Java as those 2 are my main languages. Please let me know if this is not the case, as I cannot find anything about this online. All I have to go off is chatGPT and PhpStorm warning, which isn't that helpful.

Comment: JavaScript will let you do pretty much whatever you want until runtime. Your IDE, on the other hand, guided as it is by its interpretation of JSDoc, may not. Seeing as how you've only defined one signature for the `PageDots` constructor, and one (or two, depending on how you count optional parameters) for `DDDSelector`, it's not clear which you're talking about, or what warning you're getting (which ideally would be in text in the question rather than hidden in an image).

Comment: PHPstorm doesn't really give much info on warnings. All i know is that its a Signature Mismatch Warning. The warning is given from the ```PageDots.constructor``` as its the one overriding the ```DDDSelector.constructor```. Its works fine in runtime No warnings or errors. This may be a problem with the IDE or my JSdoc

Comment: Please could you share a file/sample project that reproduces the issue?